# Why is my cv::Mat-Matrix sparse insted of dense?

Tags: opencv

due to my current work with OpenVino I have to use OpenCV. I have to convert a std::vector to a cv::Mat-array. My exemplaric code looks like this:

```
    std::vector<float> inputvector(10*10,1.1111);
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(10,10,CV_32FC1);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            image.at<float>(i,j) = inputvector.at(10*i+j);
        }
    }
```

Now I have to wrap my data by Blob::Ptr without allocation of new memory:

```
    Blob::Ptr imgBlob = wrapMat2Blob(image);
```

For the last line above I get the following error message from OpenVINO inference engine:

```
    Doesn't support conversion from not dense cv::Mat
```

I do not understand this as my 10*10 array holds the 1.1111-value in every position. Can somebody explain that? Thanks!

Comment: `Mat` represents a dense array (there's a different datatype for sparse mats). I guess [this](https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/blob/master/demos/common/samples/ocv_common.hpp#L53) is the implementation of `wrapMat2Blob` -- the implementation of the test seems rather flakey, since it will only work for images with 8bit elements (but never validates the input matrix datatype to at least provide a meaningful error). For example 32FC1 has `strideW` of 4, even though it's 1 channel, since each element takes 4 bytes.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your answer! I was able to solve the issue by only copying the line I want from the link you added: Blob::Ptr eliasBlob = InferenceEngine::make_shared_blob<uint8_t>(tDesc1,image1.data);

Comment: @tre95 where di you get the values of tDesc1,image1.data?